Strange pattern in Java H.261 Encoder frame output
I am creating a H.261 Encoder in Java:
https://github.com/ericynt/h26x-playground
To make the Encoder I used the H.261 standard documentation:
https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.261-198811-S!!PDF-E&type=items
The structure of the application is:
FrameGenerator --[RGB frames]--> H261Encoder --[H261 packets]--> UdpStreamer --[UDP datagrams]--> 127.0.0.1:55555
What the RGB frame input looks like
What the Encoder output looks like
The expected Encoder output should be the same as the input, but with minor loss in quality from the compression algorithm.
Block ordering inside a macroblock according to the standard documentation
It looks like the macroblocks are in the right place in the frame, but somehow they are not shown correctly. I cannot find what the issue is. As far as I know I am following the standard, but I must of missed something..
If I would have to guess where it is going wrong I would say in the toBlocks method at the Y component part (but I could be wrong):
    private int[][][] toBlocks (
            final Pair<Integer, Integer> pixelRowAndColumn,
            final int[][][] yCbCr
    ) {

        // YCbCr 4:4:4 to 4:2:0
        // and transform 16x16x3 to 6x8x8 (4 Y, 1 Cb, 1 Cr)

        int[][][] blocks = new int[TOTAL_BLOCKS][BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
        int[][] cbAccumulators = new int[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
        int[][] crAccumulators = new int[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
        int[][] countAccumulators = new int[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

        for (int i = pixelRowAndColumn.getKey(); i < pixelRowAndColumn.getKey() + MACROBLOCK_SIZE; i++) {

            for (int j = pixelRowAndColumn.getValue(); j < pixelRowAndColumn.getValue() + MACROBLOCK_SIZE; j++) {

                int x = i % 16;
                int y = j % 16;

                // Y component
                if (x < 8 && y < 8) {

                    // Bottom left
                    blocks[2][x][y] = yCbCr[i][j][0];
                } else if (x < 8) {

                    // Top left
                    blocks[0][x][y - 8] = yCbCr[i][j][0];
                } else if (y < 8) {

                    // Bottom right
                    blocks[3][x - 8][y] = yCbCr[i][j][0];
                } else {

                    // Top right
                    blocks[1][x - 8][y - 8] = yCbCr[i][j][0];
                }

                // Cb and Cr components
                int cbCrX = x / 2;
                int cbCrY = y / 2;

                cbAccumulators[cbCrX][cbCrY] += yCbCr[i][j][1];
                crAccumulators[cbCrX][cbCrY] += yCbCr[i][j][2];
                countAccumulators[cbCrX][cbCrY]++;
            }
        }

        // Calculate and assign the averages for Cb and Cr
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                blocks[4][i][j] = cbAccumulators[i][j] / countAccumulators[i][j];
                blocks[5][i][j] = crAccumulators[i][j] / countAccumulators[i][j];
            }
        }

        return blocks;
    }

My question is: what is the reason for the strange pattern in the output and how can I resolve it?

After searching for the cause of the problem for a few hours I finally found what the issue is.
While looking through an implementation of a H.261 encoder in C I found a transpose method. As far as I know there is no mention of this in the standard documentation.
https://github.com/maikmerten/p64/blob/cfba372679f6683a45c95817d9ed51c09566ce31/transform.c#L38
After adding a method that transposes the matrix and flipping the Y component blocks vertically the issue is resolved!
The frames now look the same as the input, except for some light artifacts from the compression algorithm, as expected
correct encoder output
